# comparing strings using !=

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I am trying to compare a striong using || operator..

```
if(publisher != "Niho books" || publisher != "Diamond Comics" )
```

what is wrong in this ? Strings can't be compared like this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `!=` or `==` to compare strings in Java. Use `.equals()` instead. The `!=` and `==` operators compare *references*, not the content of objects.

```
if (!publisher.equals("Niho books") || !publisher.equals("Diamond Comics"))
```

Comment: OP's asking why he should'nt use `!=` to compare Strings.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So, that's what I explained, didn't I...?

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
if (!"Niho books".equals(publisher) || !"Diamond Comics".equals(publisher))
```

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html

- Dont use `==`, `!=` for String compare
- `equals()` can go after publisher or after your string (`publisher.equals()` or `"string".equals()`) , I think the second one is maybe better because if your publisher is a `null` you wont get nullpointer exception. But do however you like/is right for you

Answer (score 4):

In this way you are not comparing contents... you are comparing references.

If you want to compare contents then use

```
publisher.equals("Niho books")

or 

publisher.equalsIgnoreCase("Niho books")
```

Answer (score 2):

In strings, **equals()**  tests the equality of value where as != and == tests equality of the references.

Answer (score 1):

no, strings should be compared like this:

```
publisher.equals("Niho books")
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml read this